# How to read, separate, and use input data

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate

I'm trying to develop an iOS app that will basically act as a GUI for a telnet session.  I have finally gotten the `NSStream` coding to work (mostly) and now I'm trying to figure out how to create certain events based on code results.  I think the way to do this would be to examine the results and run a "predicate" on them.  Simple example below:

I press a button that sends a command, for example the command:

> "info"

The server sends a response (which I'm currently snagging and writing in my `NSLog`):

> Version: 1.1.1
>
> Model: xyzabc
>
> Whatever: whatever
>
> Etc: etc..

How would I be able to pull that information, read it, and just take the "1.1.1" or the "xyzabc" and add it to a label in my VC?

I don't need the basics of how to add it to the label, just how to strip the correct information and stick the values into an NSString.

Thanks in advance,

Chuck
(total iOS coding NOOB)

(Edit, some code added):

```
            if (nil != output) {
                NSLog(@"%@", output);
                [self messageReceived:output];
                _txtLabel = output;


-(void)messageReceived:(NSString *)message {
    [_messages addObject:message];
}
```

_txtLabel is a NSString
_messages is a NSMutableArray

oh, and the NSLog looks like this when it comes in, not sure if this is relevant..:

```
2014-06-27 15:22:07.930 multiSceneTest[37480:60b] Version: 1.1.1
2014-06-27 15:22:07.930 multiSceneTest[37480:60b] Model: xyzabc
2014-06-27 15:22:07.931 multiSceneTest[37480:60b] Whatever: Whatever
```

Comment: `NSString` Class Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

Comment: What format is the response when you get it? An NSString?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure, at the end of the day it gets converted to a NSString, but I would assume that if we can "search" it before it becomes a string it would save some resources.. see above, i'll add some of the pertinent snippets of code.  Thanks for the quick responses!! :)

Comment: Nothing from anyone?...